# Duplicate class found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-sdk-2.3

Duplicate class org.apache.http.Consts found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.HttpConnectionFactory found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.HttpHeaders found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.MessageConstraintException found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.GuardedBy found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.auth.AuthOption found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.auth.AuthProtocolState found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeProvider found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.auth.ChallengeState found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.auth.ContextAwareAuthScheme found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.AuthCache found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.AuthenticationStrategy found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.BackoffManager found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.ConnectionBackoffStrategy found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig$Builder found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.DeflateDecompressingEntity found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.DeflateInputStream found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.DeflateInputStream$DeflateStream found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.EntityBuilder found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipCompressingEntity found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.GzipDecompressingEntity found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.AbstractExecutionAwareRequest found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.AbstractExecutionAwareRequest$1 found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.AbstractExecutionAwareRequest$2 found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.Configurable found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpExecutionAware found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper$1 found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestWrapper$HttpEntityEnclosingRequestWrapper found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder$InternalEntityEclosingRequest found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder$InternalRequest found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.params.HttpClientParamConfig found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAcceptEncoding found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestClientConnControl found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestExpectContinue found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseContentEncoding found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.DateUtils$DateFormatHolder$1 found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.HttpClientUtils found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.Idn found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.JdkIdn found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.Punycode found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.Rfc3492Idn found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.concurrent.Cancellable found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.ConnectionConfig found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.ConnectionConfig$Builder found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.Lookup found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.MessageConstraints found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.MessageConstraints$Builder found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.Registry found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig$Builder found in modules jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3) and jetified-httpcore-4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionRequest found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)
Duplicate class org.apache.http.conn.DnsResolver found in modules jetified-httpclient-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3) and jetified-httpclient-android-4.3 (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.3)

Comment: Hey @Sahil Bansal did you find any solution for this..?

Comment: I found just a way to avoid this , remove ofuscation from the gradle.-@Kriti

Answer (score 2):

You have conflicting dependencies of Apache's httpclient-android and httpcore.
This could occur in several scenarios with direct or transitive dependencies or both.
Depending on that, the proper resolution is different.

1. You have a project with more than 1 module and you include the http libraries more than once.
   Solution: In this case, include it only in the library module using "api org.apache..." instead of "implementation" and this way you will make it visible for the other modules that include that library module.
2. You include the httpclient/core directly using a gradle dependency, but one of your other dependencies already includes it.
   Solution: Remove your direct dependency from gradle.
3. (most likely)You are using 2 different libraries that both depend on the conflicting library.
   Here your best attempt will be to exclude them. In your application level build.gradle add:

   ```
   configurations {
       all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
       all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpcore'
   }
   ```

More information on dependency resolution erros:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors